# Logstash s3 output wrote format logstash s3 input doesn't understand

Tags: amazon-s3, logstash

I'm moving data from two ES clusters which are seperated.  I've added s3 as a common area and have two logstash instances, one that writes to s3 from Elasticsearch and another that reads S3 and loads Elasticsearch.

The problem is that only one document from each index is loaded.  The output file written by s3 output plugin is a single long line, with many json documents all run together without commas or opening or closing square brackets for the array.  For example, instead of `[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3}]` the output is writing files which read `{"id":1}{"id":2}{"id":3}`. In which case only `{"id":1}` is read by logstash using s3 as an input.

The configuration to go to s3 is:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["${ES_HOST}:${ES_PORT}"]
    index => "${ES_INDEX}"
    password => "${ES_PASS}"
    ssl => "true"
    user => "${ES_USER}"
}
  }
output {
  s3 {
      bucket => "${S3_BUCKET}"
      encoding => "gzip"
      codec => "json"
      prefix => "${S3_PREFIX}/${ES_INDEX}"
      region => "ap-southeast-2"
    }
}
```

The configuration reading S3 is:

```
input {
  s3 {
      bucket => "${S3_BUCKET}"
      codec => "json"
      prefix => "${S3_PREFIX}/${ES_INDEX}/"
      region => "ap-southeast-2"
      watch_for_new_files => false
    }
  }
output {
  stdout { }
}
```

In both cases the `${}` variables are set in the environment (bash shell).

Both servers are running logstash 7.6.0

PS: I don't think they are important, but the stdout log from logstash says:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules (file:/home/ec2-user/logstash-7.6.0/logstash-core/lib/jars/jruby-complete-9.2.9.0.jar) to method sun.nio.ch.NativeThread.signal(long)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.headius.backport9.modules.Modules
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Sending Logstash logs to /home/ec2-user/logstash-7.6.0/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2020-03-09T01:10:35,168][WARN ][logstash.config.source.multilocal] Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified
[2020-03-09T01:10:35,353][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Starting Logstash {"logstash.version"=>"7.6.0"}
[2020-03-09T01:10:37,813][INFO ][org.reflections.Reflections] Reflections took 48 ms to scan 1 urls, producing 20 keys and 40 values 
[2020-03-09T01:10:53,476][WARN ][org.logstash.instrument.metrics.gauge.LazyDelegatingGauge][main] A gauge metric of an unknown type (org.jruby.RubyArray) has been create for key: cluster_uuids. This may result in invalid serialization.  It is recommended to log an issue to the responsible developer/development team.
[2020-03-09T01:10:53,515][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Starting pipeline {:pipeline_id=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>2, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>50, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>250, "pipeline.sources"=>["/home/ec2-user/kibana/from_s3.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x1364485f run>"}
[2020-03-09T01:10:54,561][INFO ][logstash.inputs.s3       ][main] Registering s3 input {:bucket=>"my-bucket-here", :region=>"ap-southeast-2"}
[2020-03-09T01:10:55,334][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline started {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2020-03-09T01:10:55,435][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Pipelines running {:count=>1, :running_pipelines=>[:main], :non_running_pipelines=>[]}
[2020-03-09T01:10:55,833][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2020-03-09T01:10:57,507][INFO ][logstash.inputs.s3       ][main] Using default generated file for the sincedb {:filename=>"/home/ec2-user/logstash-7.6.0/data/plugins/inputs/s3/sincedb_1906e463a09b003733b719c08277c793"}
/home/ec2-user/logstash-7.6.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/awesome_print-1.7.0/lib/awesome_print/formatters/base_formatter.rb:31: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated
{
my-document-here
}
[2020-03-09T01:10:59,587][INFO ][logstash.runner          ] Logstash shut down.
```

PPS: deleting the since DB allows the one row to load, the file is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below in your s3 output plugin.

codec => "json_lines"

This does delimit each event by a new line.

s3 input plugin can still use the codec of "json".